# How do I reset an array to empty in PHP?

Tags: php

Looking through the available functions in the API, I cannot find one that will start an array from empty again.

Comment: what API are you referring to?

Answer (score 11):

If I remember correctly:

```
$myarray = array();
```

Answer (score 5):

In most cases, just assign a new array:

```
$ar = array();
```

If you really want to modify the array in-place, use [`array_splice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php):

```
array_splice($ar, 0, count($ar));
```

Answer (score 3):

You just set your variable to a new blank array.

```
$array = array();
```

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays (actually, since 2012) we can use:

```
$array = [];
```

More elegant and consistent with other languages.

Answer (score 1):

```
$myarray=array(); // Reset $myarray to an empty array.
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, don't use unset( $array );  The execution time is way longer than = array();